# Entity Framework avoid LazyLoading / already open DataReader issue

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, lazy-loading, union

With an Union Query which runs several times successively I get `UserlistSection` objects for each alphabetic letter, if `Users` exist with the starting letter.
So I get something like this:

- UserlistSection "A"

  - User
  - User
- UserlistSection "H"

  - User
- UserlistSection "Y"

  - User
  - User
  - User

But the query throws following exception

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
```

The query Task

```
public UserRepository(myDatabase database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

public Task<ObservableCollection<User>> GetUserFriendsAsync(int id, string letter)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var query1 = (from urs in _database.user_relationships
                              join u in _database.users on urs.relationship_user_from equals u.user_id
                              where urs.relationship_user_to == id
                                    && u.user_name.StartsWith(letter)
                                    && urs.relationship_status == 1
                              select new User
                              {
                                  Id = u.user_id,
                                  Username = u.user_name,
                                  AvatarByte = u.user_avatar,
                                  Gender = u.user_gender,
                                  GroupId = u.user_usergroup,
                                  LoginStatusId = u.user_loginstatus
                              });

                var query2 = (from urs in _database.user_relationships
                              join u in _database.users on urs.relationship_user_to equals u.user_id
                              where urs.relationship_user_from == id
                                    && u.user_name.StartsWith(letter)
                                    && urs.relationship_status == 1
                              select new User
                              {
                                  Id = u.user_id,
                                  Username = u.user_name,
                                  AvatarByte = u.user_avatar,
                                  Gender = u.user_gender,
                                  GroupId = u.user_usergroup,
                                  LoginStatusId = u.user_loginstatus
                              });

                // Union to get users via relationships (from - to and to - from)
                var queryUnion = query1.Union(query2).OrderBy(u => u.Username);

                return new ObservableCollection<User>(queryUnion);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("UserRepository - GetUserFriendsAsync" + ex);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

And my Object / Method to create the Collection

```
public class UserlistSection : ObservableObject
{
    #region Attributes

    private string _letter;
    private ObservableCollection<User> _users;

    #endregion Attributes

    public string Letter
    {
        get { return _letter; }
        set { Set(ref _letter, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
        set { Set(ref _users, value); }
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

 public async void UpdateFriendlistCollection()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        Friendlist = new ObservableCollection<UserlistSection>();

        for (var c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
        {
            try
            {
                var letter = c.ToString();
                var userCollection = await _userRepository.GetUserFriendsAsync(_userObj.Id, letter);

                if (userCollection.Count < 1) return;

                foreach (var friend in userCollection)
                {
                    friend.AvatarImage = friend.GetAvatarImgByPixel(200);
                }

                var section = new UserlistSection
                {
                    Letter = letter,
                    Users = userCollection
                };

                Friendlist.Add(section);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("FriendlistViewModel - UpdateFriendlistCollection: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        IsLoading = false;
    }
```

There are probably better ways to build the query, but I couldn't figure out how yet. So would be nice if someone can see my mistakes to avoid the LazyLoading / solve the exception.

If I'm missing some explanation, please just tell.

**Edit**

When I add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` like that, it tells me that the keyword isn't support?

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="someDatabase"   connectionString="metadata=res://*/Repository.Database.SomeDatabase.csdl|res://*/Repository.Database.SomeDatabase.ssdl|res://*/Repository.Database.SomeDatabase.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=127.0.0.1;user id=someUser;persistsecurityinfo=True;password=somePassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;database=someDatabase;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported.
Parametername: multipleactiveresultsets
bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetOption(String key)
bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String  keyword, Object value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable MARS in your connectionstring in config.

Add `"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"` to connection string.

More [info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx).

**EDIT**

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb896272(v=vs.100).aspx):

> When you call the Load method during a foreach (C#) or For Each
>   (Visual Basic) enumeration, the Entity Framework tries to open a new
>   data reader. This operation will fail unless you have enabled multiple
>   active results sets by specifying multipleactiveresultsets=true in the
>   connection string. For more information, see Using Multiple Active
>   Result Sets (MARS) on MSDN. You can also load the result of the query
>   into a List collection, which closes the data reader and enables you
>   to enumerate over the collection to load referenced entities

**EDIT**

For MySQL i found [this](http://blog.willbeattie.net/2011/05/using-entity-framework-4-with-mysql.html#comment-618283339). Mayby it helps you.

It seems that MySQL does not support MARS. If you can change the database for MS SQL Server Express. Or change the ORM for example NHibernate.

Comment: But isn't it the "dirty" way to solve this? Isn't there another solution possible in my case?

Comment: @Daniel EF works in this way. He usually need more than one data reader.

Comment: Have some issues with the connection string when I add the keyword.. added it in question.

Comment: @Daniel Config is case sensitive. You added `multipleactiveresultsets` but you should add `MultipleActiveResultSets`

Comment: I'm not into stored procedures and stuff.. so could you tell/link me how should I use that.. and what is meant with MySQL Client Library? So I need to throw my Union in C# away?

Comment: @Daniel It seems that MySQL does not support MARS.

Comment: And... 2 hours of angrily reading how my readers are stepping on each other when they're not finally end. THANK YOU.